Compiles but doesn't publish executables or dll when running build through MSBuild on Jenkins
I have created a freestyle project on Jenkins to build a .NET Web API application that compiles but doesn't output any executables(.exe) or class library(.dll) after a successfull build. I have checked 'workspace' & 'jobs' directory within Jenkins but enither contains files can be directly published.
Here you can see the output when I check the archive.

Similarly, the same result on workspace.

This is the result I expect, achieved directly by running a build from Visual Studio.


When Jenkins runs MSBuild, which file is passed to MSBuild as the project file? What file is used as the project file when you build in Visual Studio?

Hi @JonathanDodds. Here are some MSBuild details;

MSBuild Build File
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\JAMM.API\Jenkins-Test.sln
Command Line Arguments
/p:Configuration=Release

